# Instrução PHP executada diretamente pelo MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Atualmente, como o envio do email estava dando um lag na aplicação, porque tem que conectar com o Gmail etc, eu transferi para o **servidor**  a missão de enviar essas mensagens, da seguinte forma:

- Usuário grava na `tbl_msg` a mensagem e o destinatario.
- No servidor eu tenho uma pagina aberta que fica dando reload a cada 10 segundos.
- Essa página busca na base de dados os dados na `tbl_msg`, quando encontra, executa um código PHP que envia o email.

Dessa forma a aplicação para o usuário nao sofre lag algum.

**O que eu quero**

É possível o próprio banco fazer alguma coisa que caso algum dado seja gravado na `tbl_msg` automaticamente o MySQL execute a instrução PHP, sem que eu tenha que ter uma pagina aberta?

Comment: Gostaria de confirmar isso numa resposta, mas não tenho certeza. Mas você pode criar um tarefa em algum tipo de [crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) que fique executando um script PHP a cada `n` segundos. Esse script verificaria se existe algum email a ser enviado e, caso exista, enviaria esse email.

Comment: Na verdade o que você deseja é executar esse processos em background, conhecidos como Workers. [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.worker.php) você pode conferir algumas dicas de como começar.

Comment: Meu servidor é windows, e eu nao acho correto deixar uma pagina aberta no servidor dando reload. Um probleminha no bronwse e as msgs nao são enviadas.

Answer (score 4):

Há como você executar funções externas no MySQL, mas é um trabalho tedioso e de manutenção complicada.

É muito mais fácil você por uma entrada no [crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) ou no [agendador de tarefas](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/schedule-task) que execute o PHP desejado a cada 10 minutos.

### Linux

Na maior parte das distros *nix a linha do crontab ficaria assim, para executar a cada 10 minutos:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * /usr/bin/php meuscript.php > /var/log/meuscript.log
```

Algumas distros suportam essa sintaxe:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php meuscript.php > /var/log/meuscript.log
```

### Windows

Basta agendar uma tarefa no [agendador](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/schedule-task) com estas características. Se quiser, pode redirecionar para um *log* e facilitar a detecção de erros e *debug*.

```
c:/caminhoparaoseu/php.exe c:/caminho/para/arquivo.php
```

Independente do OS, **certifique-se de utilizar os caminhos corretos** para as coisas no seu sistema.

### Fazendo um loop com PHP

Para intervalos pequenos de tempo, você pode pode executar um script PHP com um *loop* infinito na inicialização do sistema:

```
<?php
   set_time_limit( 0 ); // para o PHP poder rodar sem limite de tempo

   while( true ) {
       ... aqui vai a sua função do DB ...

       sleep( 10 ); // numero de segundos entre um loop e outro
   }
?>
```

> **Não acesse esse script pelo browser!** Faça pela linha de comando para não ocupar desnecessariamente um processo do servidor web. Além disso, a diretiva `max_execution_time` tem valor de default `0` pela linha de comando, permitindo o *loop* rodar indefinidamente.

Comment: Meu Servidor windows, deixar essa tarefa no agendador do windows é seguro ?

Comment: O Agendador foi feito pra esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Concordo com o apontamento do @Bacco, o agendador de tarefas é a melhor forma de sanar o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vi, é possível, mas não é simples...

Você precisa importar a **[biblioteca UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/)** no **[MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html)** para usar uma função chamada **[sys_exec](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme)**.

Então você poderia criar uma trigger para que sempre que houvesse um novo registro, a função **sys_exec** fosse chamada, e nessa chamada **executasse um comando no sistema**, que por sua vez **executasse o php**, passando como parâmetro o script **responsável pela busca dos dados e envio do e-mail**.

Eu nunca utilizei, mas eu vi isso nesta [pergunta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger). O que vai validar se funciona ou não é as suas habilidades com programação.

Comment: Nossa cara, dei uma lida rápido e isso passa longe dos meus conhecimentos. Mesmo assim obrigado, vou tentar aqui. Eu pensei que uma tarefa dessa fosse menos complicada, isso não quer dizer fácil.