# Enviar e-mail com PHP, sem intervenção humana

Tags: php, html, mysql, servidor

Eu tenho uma duvida de PHP, porém não conheço nem os **termos** que devo pesquisar. Ai vai.

Estou começando no PHP agora, e cheguei em um problema que não consigo resolver. Eu preciso enviar um e-mail quando algo especifico acontecer. 
Por exemplo: Um professor não abriu uma aula até a hora X, então o sistema envia um e-mail para a administração informando o ocorrido.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Pesquisando no próprio SOpt já tem como mandar email por PHP http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+php+is%3Aquestion e também já tem como fazer um script ficar rodando de tempos em tempos, se precisar.

Comment: Mas eu não gostaria de executar de tempos em tempos, eu gostaria de executar quando uma condição fosse satisfeita.

Comment: Para saber se na hora X a matéria foi aberta ou não, você vai precisar de uma tarefa verificando sempre se chegou na hora desejada, senão não tem jeito. É como esse caso, que resolve 100% do que vc precisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32901/70 O PHP vai rodar toda hora, mas não vai mandar email toda hora. Apenas quando um determinado evento ou condição acontecer. É aí que vai evitar a intervenção humana. O próprio PHP vai estar "de olho"  pra quando chegar a hora certa ele tomar uma providência.