# Buscar informações da tabela do banco com PHP de 10 em 10 minutos

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso buscar informações de uma tabela do banco de dados de 10 em 10 minutos utilizando a liguagem PHP. Alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O ideal seria um [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Ainda não tenho o código. Estou precisando de uma idéia do que posso usar no PHP para fazer isso. Exemplo... eu devo usar, cURL, cronjob, agendador de tarefas do Windows etc.

O cronjob é uma boa... sei que funciona muito bem no Linux, estou vendo como ele funciona no Windows.

Comment: Por que não usar `XMLHttpRequest` + `window.setTimeout`? É algo especifico ao "tempo real"? Qual o objetivo final disto?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32901/70

Answer (score 3):

O meio óbvio é criar uma entrada no [crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) ou no [agendador de tarefas](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/schedule-task) que execute o PHP desejado a cada 10 minutos.

### Linux

Na maior parte das distros *nix a linha do crontab ficaria assim, para executar a cada 10 minutos:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * /usr/bin/php meuscript.php > /var/log/meuscript.log
```

Algumas distros suportam essa sintaxe:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php meuscript.php > /var/log/meuscript.log
```

### Windows

Basta agendar uma tarefa no [agendador](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/schedule-task) com estas características. Se quiser, pode redirecionar para um *log* e facilitar a detecção de erros e *debug*.

```
c:/caminhoparaoseu/php.exe c:/caminho/para/arquivo.php
```

Independente do OS, **certifique-se de utilizar os caminhos corretos** para as coisas no seu sistema.

### PLano B: fazendo um loop com PHP

Para intervalos pequenos de tempo, você pode pode executar um script PHP com um *loop* infinito na inicialização do sistema, mas chamando fora do browser:

```
<?php
   set_time_limit( 0 ); // para o PHP poder rodar sem limite de tempo

   while( true ) {
       ... aqui vai a sua função do DB ...

       sleep( 60 ); // numero de segundos entre um loop e outro
   }
?>
```

**Mas não acesse esse último script pelo browser!** Faça pela linha de comando para não ocupar desnecessariamente um processo do servidor web. Além disso, a diretiva `max_execution_time` tem valor de default `0` pela linha de comando, permitindo o *loop* rodar indefinidamente.

Answer (score 1):

o ideal seria você utilizar cronjob para maior eficácia e manter seu código limpo.
Pelo php vc poderia deixar seu script em loop infinito:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

while (TRUE):
    if (functionQueVerificaOtime()):
        functionQueExecutaQueryNoBanco();
    endif;
endwhile;
```

Essa seria a lógica, porém tu teria um problema bem maior em deixar esse código limpo.
Caso não tenha jeito a solução ainda será essa mas recomendo desde o início utilizar o cron.

Boa sorte.

Comment: Funciona, mas as chances de sobrecarregar o processo são altas. Talvez uma solução front-end, como `XMLHttpRequest` + `window.setTimeout`, mesmo não sendo o que ele pede, talvez ele não tenha muito conhecimento de quando usar o front-end e o back-end.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal e muito recomendado é criando um cronjob no servidor chamando o arquivo PHP que faz o trabalho. Não há nada para PHP como a biblioteca Quartz para Java. Portanto, a melhor maneira é criando o CronJob mesmo. Abaixo está a sintaxe usada para se criar cronjobs.

```
[Minute] [Hour] [Day] [Month] [Day of week (0 =sunday to 6 =saturday)] [Command]
```

*O * (asterisco) é usado para representar todos os valores dos campos. Exemplo: todo minuto, ou toda hora...*

Exemplo de uma chamada cron:

```
30 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f <caminho do seu script> &> /dev/null
```

No comando acima, o chamada será executada de hora em hora no minuto 30.

Fonte: [How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)