# Temporizador em PHP

Tags: php

Estou precisando implementar uma funcionalidade, na qual um determinado código é executado varias as vezes após um intervalo de tempo.

Por exemplo, ler arquivos disponibilizados pela API em cada 20 minutos. Tentei algo de gênero, mas que ainda não testei, apenas gostaria de ter uma maneira fácil e certo de o fazer.

```
   while(true)
   {
      // Executa o codigo aqui;
      usleep(1200);

   }
```

Será que o PHP tem algum método para agendar tarefas? Qual seria o mecanismo para cancelar o *loop*, caso a ideia acima seja válida?

Comment: Francisco, não conheço o suficiente de php para responder a todas as suas perguntas, mas posso te adiantar que você pode utilizar `break;` para sair para do seu loop.

Comment: A função usleep / sleep serve para atrasar a execução de um script e não é recomendado colocar valores muito altos, porque o script vai continuar rodando até que o tempo acabe, ou seja, ele vai continuar consumindo memória durante todo o tempo de execução. Para agendar tarefas, você deve usar as ferramentas do sistema, seja ele Linux ou Windows, ambos possuem recursos para isso. No caso do Linux, o recurso chama-se cron job, no Windows é gerenciador de tarefas, se não me engano. Ambas as ferramentas irão executar seu script PHP conforme o agendamento, dispensando o uso do sleep. Use o sleep

Comment: apenas em casos bem específicos, como quando você quer fazer um atrasado em um loop que envia e-mails para evitar floodar o sistema com uma execução muito rápida.

Comment: Acho que é o mesmo problema dessa questão: [Buscar informações da tabela do banco com PHP de 10 em 10 minutos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55251/) - As respostas independem da tarefa que vai ser executada

Answer (score 2):

Cron job é a forma mais correta de se fazer ;)

Chama um index.php a cada minuto:

```
1 * * * * wget www.meusite.pt/crons/index.php
```

Depois dentro desse ficheiro php é so fazer uns "ifs":

```
ore_user_abort();
set_time_limit(3600);

// a cada hora
if(date('i')==59){
    $this->hour();
}

// a cada minuto
$this->minute();
```

Algo por ai... Alguma duvida avisa ;)

Abraço e bons projetos!