# Como rodar o mesmo script php via cron sem sobrecarregar?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, sobrecarga

Qual o melhor caminho para rodar um mesmo script php várias vezes fazendo consultas randômicas para uma determinada coluna com um limite de 1000 por consulta de uma mesma tabela mysql via cron (cpanel) sem gerar tanta sobrecarga?

[cron 1]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 2]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 3]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 4]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 5]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 6]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 7]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 8]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 9]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

[cron 10]

```
*   *   *   *   *   curl -s http://[::1]/dir/arquivo.php
```

Comment: A primeira coisa é arrancar correndo esse curl daí. Se viu isso como exemplo em alguma postagem aqui do SOpt para acesso à maquina local, avise qual foi pra gente dar uma olhada, pq é absurdo. O PHP tem o executável de linha de comando que é muito mais adequado para isso (e não vai ficar travando tarefa do servidor web). Veja um exemplo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56171/70 e outro aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124519/70 - Sobre o fato de ter 10 entradas no cron, não consigo imaginar uma razão pra isso. Se puder elaborar melhor, talvez ajude a esclarecer a pergunta.

Comment: Oi @Bacco, obrigado pela disposição em ajudar. 1. Peço que releve a url :)   Eu usava o /usr/bin/php antes de investir no curl. Vários lugares sugerem esses dois métodos, além do lynx e do wget.

Mas o que estou tentando descobrir é como evitar ou amenizar a sobrecarga no servidor. Se é que isso seja possível. A ideia de ter dez entradas é para conseguir processar 1.500.000 de linhas por dia com previsão de dobrar isso em breve...

Comment: Isso normalmente é para acessar coisa de terceiros. Localmente se alguém usa lynx, wget e curl tendo o executável do PHP, melhor desconfiar. Simplesmente você estará ocupando à toa o servidor de páginas, e obrigando o PHP a ter timeout.

Comment: Mas @Bacco, além de trocar essa parada do curl, normal executar n vezes o mesmo script que puxará aleatoriamente os registros de um seller entre dezenas para eu conseguir processar mais rápido todos os registros?

Comment: Quanto mais entrada no crontab, pior é. Só vai ficar fazendo concorrência entre as tarefas paralelas. Se tem algo demorado no seu php, é lá que vai ter que corrigir. Mas com o que foi postado na pergunta, não há muito o que dizer. E precisa ver se PHP é a ferramenta certa para o que vc quer fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa criar 200 entradas cron, para fazer a mesma coisa, isso vai afetar o desempenho do seu servidor, causando sobrecarga mesmo, desnecessariamente, ainda mais usando **curl**.

Primeiro, através do bloco de notas, crie um shell script, com o seguinte texto:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONSULT=$((($RANDOM %1000) + 1))
$ php -q /path/dir/arquivo.php $CONSULT
```

Salve ele com a extensão: **.sh**, observe que o comando **-q** (indica que você está enviando a requisição via GET para sua URL).

Agora jogue no seu servidor, com o nome de script.sh, dê permissão de execução nele (se for através do cpanel, basta incluir o cron, e solicitar aos administradores a configuração de execução, se tiver acesso via ssh, você mesmo pode fazer isso):

`sudo chmod +x  /path/dir/script.sh`

Basta uma única rotina, ele fará de acordo com o tempo que você definir para ser executado, exemplo, abaixo ele fará à cada 5 minutos:

`5 * * * * http://path/dir/script.sh`

Agora dentro do seu arquivo.php, verifique o argumento passado, [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php), é uma variável reservada:

```
<?php

    if (count($argv)) {
       // o primeiro argumento $argv[0], é o nome do script: arquivo.php
       $limit = $argv[1]; /* captura o segundo argumento
                             passado,que é no caso,
                             o número aleatório de 1 a 1000,
                             representado pela variável $CONSULT do shell */
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 0, {$limit}";
    ...
```